# grails test-app MetaDataAccessException after upgrade to mysql-connector-java:5.1.34

Tags: mysql, grails, mysql-connector

I recently upgraded to the mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34 connector.  My Grails version is 2.2.4.  MySQL version is 5.6.10. Upgrading went very smoothly, and the application itself seems to go fine.  However, one of my test apps is failing.
The following error happens:

```
Error Error executing script TestApp: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor':
Initialization of bean failed; 
nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' 
while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; 
nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' 
while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; 
nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' 
while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect];
nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': 
Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is 
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: 
Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; 
nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: 
Access denied for user 'web'@'localhost' (using password: YES) 
(Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

I doublechecked the web user, and as far as I can tell the account is defined properly and has admin privs comparable to root.  This has happened both on my development box with my personal database and on our jenkins build system.

I don't see anything in the logs, Running with --stacktrace does not give me any useful information, googling does not show this as a common error.

Comment: Can you connect with that username and password from a MySQL client? MySQL authentication uses a username, password, and host name or ip address. A driver upgrade shouldn't have affected this though.

Comment: Yes,  there are no problems accessing MySQL directly with the client.

Comment: Could you edit the question to show your DataSource.groovy?